# Daily schedule skips a day every now and then [pentaho-server 7.1]

Tags: quartz-scheduler, pentaho

I have a pentaho-server CE with more than 150 schedules that have different frequencies, monthly daily, weekly, etc. However I am having strange behavior every now and then, where a daily schedule is not executed every day. It is strangely happening every monday.

Actually, today is the 3rd Monday in a row, when this daily schedule was not executed. Here is the screenshot from scheduler where you can see that there are 3 daily schedules, but only 2 were executed last night:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/509014679687921679/567242288128851998/schedule_en.png

Is there anything, that could make this schedule to not execute at mondays? Its been up for few months already and it never happened before. I have also checked localhost.loq and catalina.out and all other logs but there is nothing there from the time when this schedule should be executed.

Comment: through screen-shot one can't get any idea.. share some more details.

Comment: well, I am not sure what details are helpfull there, as everything is pretty standard. I have no custom code in my pentaho installation and schedules are aso pretty standard, through GUI created daily schedules that execute *.prpt files. However I will answer any question anybody ask..

Answer (score 1):

My dear friend, this a common issue for me on Pentaho 8.0.

Maybe my enviroment is different, because I'm running a cluster.

In my case, when I schedule multiple tasks with the same time, in someway, they "collide", and just one of them runs. For that reason, I use tu put a one minute difference between them and voila! they just keep running without issues.